# Find and replace various substrings in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find various values and replace/annonymise them, e.g.:

```
DATA.str.replace(['Banana', 'banana', 'galaxy', 'S9'],['CpyX', 'CpyX', 'ProductA', 'ProductB'],inplace=True)
```

If the string is matched exactly, it works.

However, if I have, for example, `'Test Bananas'`, it does not replace `Banana`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `regex=True` in your args

```
df.replace(from, to, regex=True)
```

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['String Number One', 'String Number Two']})

    col1
0   String Number One
1   String Number Two
```

such that

```
df.replace('Number', 'NewWord')

    col1
0   String Number One
1   String Number Two
```

However,

```
df.replace('Number', 'NewWord', regex=True)

    col1
0   String NewWord One
1   String NewWord Two
```

works as expected.

Comment: this worked great thank you. I did realize those that ideally I would like the replace to be case insensitive is there a way to include that?

Answer (score 0):

LIke

```
d=dict(zip(['Banana', 'banana', 'galaxy', 'S9'],['CpyX', 'CpyX', 'ProductA', 'ProductB'])
DATA.replace(d,inplace=True,regex=True)
```